# How do you solve a differential equation like $\frac{dy}{dx} = tan^2(x + y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation using an appropriate substitution.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = tan^2(x + y)$

I tried having $y=ux$

Therefore:

$u'x + u = tan^2(x + ux)$

$= tan^2(x(1 + u))$

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $$u=x+y$$ then we have $$y'=u'-1$$ and we get
$$u'=\tan^2(u)+1$$ and we have $$u'=\frac{1}{\cos^2(u)}$$

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand something. If $y = u-x$, how do you differentiate both sides like that? $dy = u - dx$? Why does $u$ stay the same and $x$ becomes $1$?

Comment: It is $$u`=1+y'$$ so $$y'=u'-1$$

Comment: you wrote $y' = u - 1$ in your answer. please change it so i can accept answer

Comment: Thank you for your hint, it is corrected!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \tan^2(x + y)$$
$$\cos ^2 (x+y) y' = \sin^2(x + y)$$
$$\cos ^2 (x+y) y' +\cos^2(x + y)= \sin^2(x + y)+\cos^2(x + y)$$
$$\cos ^2 (x+y)( y' +1)= 1$$
$$\cos ^2 (x+y)( y+x)'= 1$$
Finally integrate:
$$\int \cos ^2 (x+y)d(x+y)= \int dx$$
The original equation is also an exact differential
$$ \cos^2(x+y){dy} - \sin^2(x + y)dx=0$$